# What is the definition of convexity from $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: convex-analysis

$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1- \lambda) f(y)$. This is the definition of convexity I am used to. If $f$ is a convex function, then $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

What if I am doing something like $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Is the definition of convexity different or is it still the same?

So instead of $f(x)$ I had $f(x,y)$. If the definition is different what would it look like then?

Comment: Yes, the definition generalizes as you said. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition

Comment: Replace lines with planes.

Comment: You confuse notation of $x,y$. So assume $x\in R^n$. The convexity $f(x)$ is defined in the same way.

Comment: So if $Z \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a convex subset with $(x,y) \in Z$, I can take something like $f(x,y)$? Or no? I was thinking the definition would be something like $f(\lambda (x,y) + (1- \lambda) (x',y')) \leq ...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the definition is formally the same, namely
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y),\qquad x,y\in\mathbb R^2,\lambda\in[0,1].
\end{align*}
Note that here $x$ and $y$ are points in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$ runs along the line joining $x$ and $y$ when $\lambda$ runs through $[0,1]$.